# Checking if a file is being downloaded by Python Requests library

Tags: python, http, python-requests

I have been having problems with a script I am developing whereby I am receiving no output and the memory usage of the script is getting larger and larger over time. I have figured out the problem lies with some of the URLs I am checking with the Requests library. I am expecting to download a webpage however I download a large file instead. All this data is then stored in memory causing my issues.

What I want to know is; is there any way with the requests library to check what is being downloaded? With wget I can see: Length: 710330974 (677M) [application/zip].

Is this information available in the headers with requests? If so is there a way of terminating the download upon figuring out it is not a HTML webpage?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the headers can tell you a lot about the page, *most* pages will include a Content-Length header.

By default, however, the request is downloaded in its entirety before the `.get()` or `.post()`, etc. call returns. Set the `stream=True` keyword to defer loading the response:

```
response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
```

Now you can inspect the headers and just discard the request if you don't like what you find:

```
length = int(response.headers.get('Content-Length', 0))
if length > 1048576:
    print 'Response larger than 1MB, discarding
```

Subsequently accessing the `.content` or `.text` attributes, or the `.json()` method will trigger a full download of the response.